# Write each row individually and add date in empty column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have the following code in an Excel VBA module that looks up the *ProjID* named cell on the worksheet, selects columns needed for output from *dbo_Proj_Dash* Access table (and properly connects fields across multiple tables, where needed), then writes the entire recordset to the Excel sheet.

```
Dim AccessOutput As ADODB.Recordset
Set AccessOutput = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLQuery As String

SQLQuery = "SELECT dbo_Proj_Dash.ID, dbo_Proj_Dash.Dash_Num, dbo_Proj_Dash.Dash_Desc, dbo_Proj_Dash_Type.Dash_Type, dbo_Proj_Dash.Dash_Qty, dbo_Proj_Dash.Dash_Unit, dbo_Proj_Dash_Mfr.MfrIni, dbo_Mng_Users.UserIni, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_TargetSubmit, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_ActualSubmit "
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery & ",dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_TargetApprove, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_ActualApprove, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_TargetRLSMfr, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_ActualRlsMfr, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_TargetShip, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_ActualShip, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_TargetInstallFinish, dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_ActualInstallFinish "
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery & ",dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_DashUpdate "
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery & "FROM ((dbo_Proj_Dash LEFT JOIN dbo_Proj_Dash_Type ON dbo_Proj_Dash.Dash_Type = dbo_Proj_Dash_Type.ID) LEFT JOIN dbo_Proj_Dash_Mfr ON dbo_Proj_Dash.Mfg = dbo_Proj_Dash_Mfr.ID) LEFT JOIN dbo_Mng_Users ON dbo_Proj_Dash.Dwg_Draftsman = dbo_Mng_Users.ID "
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery & "WHERE (((dbo_Proj_Dash.Proj_ID)= " & ProjID & " )) "
    SQLQuery = SQLQuery & "ORDER BY dbo_Proj_Dash.ID ASC"

          
AccessOutput.Open SQLQuery, DBConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly

sht.Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset AccessOutput
```

I need help to rewrite this code so it writes each line individually. Additionally, I need to add code to, if available,  write Date/Time from *dbo_Proj_Dash.Date_DashUpdate* to the Excel sheet for each line (should write to Column S/19); if unavailable, write the current Date/Time and trigger function *LogActivity* (which writes to a separate Access table/log, *UserActivityLog*).

Comment: If you want to write each record individually, then loop through recordset and loop through fields. As far as I can see, Date_DashUpdate is already included in the SQL to associate with each record. And as for trigger of function LogActivity, call it in the loop. Do research on looping recordset and attempt code and when you have specific issue, post question. If data is maintained in Access, why is Excel involved?

Comment: If Date_DashUpdate field in that SQL is Null, then use a dynamic input to populate whatever date value you want. Can simply concatenate `", #" & Date() & "# AS Date_DashUpdate "`.

Comment: However, I suspect what you want can be accomplished without looping recordset, including write to Access log table.

Comment: @June7 you've asked the same question on my other post and my answer is still the same -- that's what my boss wants lol

Comment: Okay, did not realize we already discussed. And as for the dynamic date, correction - don't even have to concatenate since Date() is a function SQL can understand: `", Date() AS Date_DashUpdate "`.

Comment: @June7 Finally was able to write the code to loop through and copy over instead of copying the entire recordset over to Excel, but the handling of the Date_DashUpdate field is a bit more involved than I initially posted (it's now updated to refect the following).

I actually need to first determine if there's an existing value for Dash_DashUpdate on the Access table -- if so, simply copy over; if not, THEN that's when I need to write the current Date/Time and run the LogActivity function to add a log entry.